# How to Upgrade File based Sql Server Express database(mdf) during Desktop application setup installation

Tags: .net, desktop-application, sql-server-express, setup-deployment, mdf

**What is already done.**
I have built a windows form application using .Net Framework 4.5 and File Based Sql Server Express Database(mdf) which is installed and running at client machines.

**New Change requirement?**
New requirement got introduced So I added new columns in some tables and some new tables in database and build and ran it on my local machine which is running fine.

**What is requirement?**
I need to save every client application data with database upgradation I have applied during installation.

**What I have tried to achieve this requirement?** 
I tried it with standard installation setup, When I try to install in standard way it deletes existing data file and re-install it, Due to which I lost existing data.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in your application. Introduce a new table called "Version" and store there the version of the schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Version (VersionNumber int)
```

Store the SQL upgrade scripts in your application. Every script should be belong to a version number.

Check version number after application's start and run every necessary script. After you ran a particular script, insert the version number into the table.

If the Version table does not exists at all, then simply create it and run all the scripts.

Comment: Thanks, But What about existing database deletion problem, when I re-install or upgrade application it deletes existing files.

Comment: Very simple: store the data file in a different location. For example "Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData" (= C:\ProgramData -
 shared across users).